# Is it a good practice to extend classes to store additional information?

Tags: java, swing, oop, inheritance, extends

I was wondering if it is a good practice to extend classes which were made, in a first moment, to be used without the need to extend it, just to add some information that you will be using in the application in a further moment.

For example, I was using the Swing Java API to create a GUI for a application I was developing. While building it, I had the necessity to create a JTable which model would be changed several times on the runtime depending on what the user did. So, I had like three different models that could be applied to that JTable depending on the situation. That said, in my application I realized that it would be much more easier to me if I could extend the JTable and create another class which would have a Enum (or any other type) internally which could provide me which model is active on the JTable in the exact moment that I've checked it. So, my question is: Is it a good practice to extend, for example, that JTable, just to add fields that have information that will probably be useful to access in the application? For me, it would be a lot easier to hold this information directly in the JTable and access it whenever I have access to JTable.

Is it a good practice? Horrible practice? What your opinion? Thanks!

Comment: If you could give an example, that would be nice, but I don't see any problem with extending a class to add information. Although, it may not be as necessary, if it helps you, it sounds alright. If you're speaking convention-wise, I'm not sure, but once again, I think it will be fine, but if you're speaking performance wise, it shouldn't affect too much, but testing would be required to verify.

Comment: Maybe you're looking at using the Decorator Design Pattern perhaps? Although that may be overkill for what you're doing -- I can't tell since I don't fully understand your actual code and problem.

Comment: Reading your comments, I start to think doing it is not a terrible practice, but should be used only when really necessary. Am I correct? In the situation that I described before, I had the opportunity to solve the problem without subclassing the JTable, of course. But, again, if I had subclassed it, I guess it would have reduced my work a lot. So, in your opinion, it is a good practice to do it everytime you find it useful or you think it's better to use it only when it's REALLY necessary?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming an M-V-C or Model-View-Control program structure, or something reasonably close to this,

> ...create a JTable which model would be changed several times on the runtime depending on what the user did. So, I had like three different models that could be applied to that JTable depending on the situation.

Key here is this: what is actually changing? The JTable or its TableModel? If the TableModel, I would avoid sub-classing JTable.

> That said, in my application I realized that it would be much more easier to me if I could extend the JTable and create another class which would have a Enum (or any other type) internally which could provide me which model is active on the JTable in the exact moment that I've checked it.

This seems to confuse View with Model. The TableModel information should be part of the program's Model, and if it changes, you could then have the Model notify listeners of the change.

> So, my question is: Is it a good practice to extend, for example, that JTable, just to add fields that have information that will probably be useful to access in the application? For me, it would be a lot easier to hold this information directly in the JTable and access it whenever I have access to JTable.

In this situation, I would not subclass JTable but rather have significant state changes and their notifications be part of the main program's Model, not its View (as you're trying to do).

Comment: I got your point and your answer was very useful. However, I was trying to ask a general question. Maybe the JTable's example wasn't the best example to give, but forgetting about this example, I was trying to ask if is it a good practice to subclass classes to add useful information when it is, actually, a correct situation to do it

Comment: @user3513453: then I fear that your question may be too broad as it really boils down to the larger debate about inheritance vs. composition. In my mind, the specific situation is mainly what matters and what drives the decision.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, extending classes this way is good java.

If a class is not meant to be extended it should be declared final.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your application business requirements and architectural strategy, but this is a common design pattern with the `Decorator` pattern.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern